# Convert Function Based View to Class Based View

Tags: python, django

I have a Django 2.1 views.py that I wanted to convert to Class Based View, I am NOT Django advanced user, and I know that I did translate the Functions the wrong way. The code was ment to serve a Bootstrap Modal Ajax form, and don't ask me to go see some solution already built out there, I tried everything, even the ones that worked fine in standalone, they are not compatible/conflict with my template (Maybe jquery or ..). I did convert List View and so far Create View, but I keep getting this Error :

`UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  "A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context "`

Here's my views.py that I want to convert to CBV :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from .models import Book
from .forms import BookForm
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView


#The Old function List view
#def book_list(request):
#    books = Book.objects.all()
#    return render(request, 'books/book_list.html', {'books': books})


#The New Class List view
class Book_list(ListView):
    template_name = 'books/book_list.html'
    model = Book

def save_book_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            books = Book.objects.all()
            data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_list.html', {
                'books': books
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


def book_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = BookForm()
    return save_book_form(request, form, 'books/includes/partial_book_create.html')



def book_update(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST, instance=book)
    else:
        form = BookForm(instance=book)
    return save_book_form(request, form, 'books/includes/partial_book_update.html')


def book_delete(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        book.delete()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        books = Book.objects.all()
        data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_list.html', {
            'books': books
        })
    else:
        context = {'book': book}
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_delete.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I've been strugling since 9 days now. asking around, asked even the developper of that code ... no answer..
I really appreciate it, thank you guys

Comment: The `{% csrf_token %}` warning is because you have missed out `request=request` in some of your `render_to_string()` calls. If your function based views are working, then you don't have to convert them to class based views. I can't convert your code for you, but you might find [part 4 of the tutorial useful](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial04/) (they switch from the function based views from part 3 to class based views). Also look at the [json response mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#more-than-just-html) docs.

Comment: Thank you for the catch @Alasdait, and nice tutorial you gave. but I wanted to convert it the way it should be. And yes actually I have to Convert to Class Based View, in order to inherit from classes, otherwise I'm gonna find myself with a big mess, since the project is taking size. those functions are related to Modal ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to change you view's to class based view's

```
class BookList(ListView):
    template_name = 'books/book_list.html'
    model = Book


class BookCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = "books/includes/partial_book_list.html"
    model = Book
    form_class = BookForm
    success_url = 'success' #name of url you want to redirect to


class BookUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Book
    form_class = BookForm
    fields = ['name',] #field's you want to update
    template_name = 'books/includes/partial_book_update.html'
    success_url = 'success' #name of url you want to redirect to


class BookDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'books/includes/partial_book_delete.html'
    success_url = 'success'
```

Comment: Hi @ishita thank for the quick answer. Actually I did the same thing but it doesn't work, because this function is not just sending regular rendering things as usual/default, but sending stuff related to handle a Bootstrap Modal ajax Form. For examble data context like "html_book_list" and "books"and ... as you can see in the example above, 

could you include those data context inside the converted Class that you gave me ??

Waiting like hell for the answer.

Thank you.